# How to convert a struct that includes a pointer member to JSON with Boost Describe

Tags: c++, boost, reflection, boost-json, boost-describe

In the documentation of Boost Describe, there is an example for automatic conversion of a struct to JSON (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/describe/doc/html/describe.html#example_to_json). However, when adding a pointer as a member of the struct, the code example does not work. I guess that the tag_invoke function needs to be modified in order to handle the pointer.

I tried the following, based on the example:

```
#include <boost/describe.hpp>
#include <boost/json.hpp>
#include <boost/mp11.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

namespace app{

template <
    class T,
    class D1 = boost::describe::describe_members<
        T, boost::describe::mod_public | boost::describe::mod_protected>, //
    class D2 =
        boost::describe::describe_members<T, boost::describe::mod_private>, //
    class En = std::enable_if_t<boost::mp11::mp_empty<D2>::value &&
                                !std::is_union<T>::value> //
    >   
void tag_invoke(boost::json::value_from_tag const &, boost::json::value &v, 
                T const &t) {
  auto &obj = v.emplace_object();

  boost::mp11::mp_for_each<D1>(
      [&](auto D) { obj[D.name] = boost::json::value_from(t.*D.pointer); }); 
}

int b = 0;

struct A {
  int *i;
};

BOOST_DESCRIBE_STRUCT(A, (), (i));

A a{&b};

}

int main() {
  std::cout << boost::json::value_from(app::a)
            << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your pointers are to user-defined types, you can "just" overload for the pointer:

```
template <class T>
void tag_invoke(boost::json::value_from_tag const&, boost::json::value& v, T const* p) {
    if (p)
        boost::json::value_from(*p, v);
    else
        v.emplace_null();
}
```

This works because of ADL:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9674ff4962c1cc75)**

```
#include <boost/describe.hpp>
#include <boost/json/src.hpp>
#include <boost/mp11.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace app {
    struct MyInt {
        int value;
    };

    template <class T>
    void tag_invoke(boost::json::value_from_tag const&, boost::json::value& v, T const* p) {
        if (p)
            boost::json::value_from(*p, v);
        else
            v.emplace_null();
    }

    template <class T,
              class D1 = boost::describe::describe_members<
                  T, boost::describe::mod_public | boost::describe::mod_protected>,                     //
              class D2 = boost::describe::describe_members<T, boost::describe::mod_private>,            //
              class En = std::enable_if_t<boost::mp11::mp_empty<D2>::value && !std::is_union<T>::value> //
              >
    void tag_invoke(boost::json::value_from_tag const&, boost::json::value& v, T const& t) {
        auto& obj = v.emplace_object();

        boost::mp11::mp_for_each<D1>([&](auto D) { obj[D.name] = boost::json::value_from(t.*D.pointer); });
    }

    MyInt b{42};

    struct A {
        MyInt* i;
    };

    BOOST_DESCRIBE_STRUCT(MyInt, (), (value))
    BOOST_DESCRIBE_STRUCT(A, (), (i))

    A a{&b};

} // namespace app

int main() {
    std::cout << boost::json::value_from(app::a) << std::endl;
}
```

Printing

```
{"i":{"value":42}}
```

### Primitive Types

However your type is not user-defined. Primitive types like `int` do not have any associated namespace. [The above doesn't work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/39539e67a26ba665)...

You would either have to explicitly include the overload, which requires modifying library code, *or* you can make the pointer-handling explicit in your code:

```
    boost::mp11::mp_for_each<D1>([&](auto D) {
        auto&& v = t.*D.pointer;
        if constexpr (std::is_pointer_v<std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(v)>>) {
            obj[D.name] = boost::json::value_from(*v);
        } else {
            obj[D.name] = boost::json::value_from(v);
        }
    });
```

This will work. **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d7d8c8eaf43de556)**

```
#include <boost/describe.hpp>
#include <boost/json/src.hpp>
#include <boost/mp11.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace app {
    template <class T,
              class D1 = boost::describe::describe_members<
                  T, boost::describe::mod_public | boost::describe::mod_protected>,                     //
              class D2 = boost::describe::describe_members<T, boost::describe::mod_private>,            //
              class En = std::enable_if_t<boost::mp11::mp_empty<D2>::value && !std::is_union<T>::value> //
              >
    void tag_invoke(boost::json::value_from_tag const&, boost::json::value& v, T const& t) {
        auto& obj = v.emplace_object();

        boost::mp11::mp_for_each<D1>([&](auto D) {
            auto&& v = t.*D.pointer;
            if constexpr (std::is_pointer_v<std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(v)>>) {
                obj[D.name] = boost::json::value_from(*v);
            } else {
                obj[D.name] = boost::json::value_from(v);
            }
        });
    }

    int b{42};

    struct A {
        int* i;
    };

    BOOST_DESCRIBE_STRUCT(A, (), (i))

    A a{&b};

} // namespace app

int main() {
    std::cout << boost::json::value_from(app::a) << std::endl;
}
```

Printing

```
{"i":42}
```

### Notes

Note that raw pointers are problematic at best. It will be completely unclear what to do when *deserializing* instead. I suspect you might want to look at Boost Serialization instead if you need that kind of support.